# OpenGL : (graphic problems) vertical black lines appearing in all the screen

Tags: opengl, lines, graphic

I've recently got a blue screen error. I'm not sure if problems came after the blue screen, but I think that's important to notice it.

Here is a gif of my problem :

http://img110.xooimage.com/files/6/6/7/prob-4b77771.gif

There are litle black lines appearing without reason (I never had this problem before). I think that there is a link with my graphic card, but I already did updates and it changed nothing.

Here are some informations about my computer (sorry for french) :

[image: computer informations]

I'm programming with OpenGL, Ruby language, and Gosu library.

Comment: this looks like a `vsync` problem...Also on windows, If I remember well, gl libs are shipped with graphic card drivers, ensure you're using the correct one.

Comment: But how can I know that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was actually a wrong using of graphic process. My default graphic process had been changed, so I just had to change it. (by right clicking on a programm, select execute with graphic process > change default graphic process)